# Storage device interface through MIPI CSI+DSI connections

Tags: usb, hardware, usb3

So I love the Raspberry Pi and currently own and use a model 3b (not plus) for learning more about linux and hardware as well as simple projects like a DNS cache server.  Lately I was thinking about how I could optimize the device as well as expand on its capabilities.  I try to be an outside the box thinker.

Obviously this is a non-traditional idea, but I had a thought about the use of the MIPI CSI and DSI connectors and was curious about their bandwidth since in my case the interfaces are unused. From my research online I saw that the MIPI interfaces both use only 2 data lanes, and that the CSI interface can support video capture at a max 1080p@30fps. So I calculated 1080pixels * 1920pixels * 30 fps * 16bit color = 995328000bits/sec or 995.3Mbps.  Given that there are two interfaces the theoretical throughput would be 1990.6Mbps.

So my question is would it be possible to create a bus for a SATA or USB3.0 connection(albeit not full-speed) or is their a limitation on the data that can be input/output through these interfaces?